# Is it possible to obtain a reference/pointer to an object property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reference

Specifically, I want to create an HTML `<input>` element, and obtain a reference to its `value` property such that I can change its value through that reference:

```
var input = document.createElement('input');
var valueRef = &(input.value);
*valueRef = "Hello world!"
```

The syntax is obviously pseudo, I'm adding some C++ to illustrate my desire. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is impossible. Primitives will always be passed by value while objects always passed by reference. There is nothing like `*` or `&`.

Comment: Note: objects are passed by reference in that the function can modify (or even remove) properties of the object, but really it's by value in that the "value" is a copy of a reference to a specific object - if, inside the function, you try to change the reference to point to a different object the variable outside the function will continue to point to the original object. (OK, I know I got myself in a bit of a tangle trying to explain that in a comment where I couldn't give an effective code example.)

Comment: Strictly, all variables are "passed by value", where the value can be a primitive or a reference to an object.